# Does requestAnimationFrame interfere CSS transitions?

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox-gl-js, requestanimationframe

Is it possible, that `requestAnimationFrame` prevents other CSS transitions from working?

I have a `requestAnimationFrame` function, which shall move the position of a div container. The update is done on every frame request. The div container contains a CSS animation:

```
.container {
  ...
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  ...
}

  @keyframes pulse {
    0%   { transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }
    70%  { transform: scale(3); opacity: 0; }
    100% { transform: scale(1); opacity: 0; }
  }
```

The CSS animation works fine as long as I do NOT call `requestAnimationFrame` or I stop making requests.

Additionally, calling `requestAnimationFrame` also prevents other transitions from working, which are outside of the scope of the animated container, for instance a navigation drawer, which I use as side menu.

As a work-a-round for the navigation drawer I had to wrap the request as following:

```
this.animationId = requestAnimationFrame((timestamp) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.animateContainer(timestamp)
  }, 50)
})
```

The inner `setTimeout` is used to delay the next animation to let the drawer slide in.

However, this does not help for the container animation. Whenever a new frame gets drawn, the CSS animations begins and is reset with every new frame, so the animation flickers.

EDIT:

**Why do I use requestAnimationFrame and CSS animations?**

The `requestAnimationFrame` is used to interpolate the coordinates of a marker on a map. The actual position for X and Y is being calculated by the map depending on the canvas. The CSS animation is then used to animate that marker.

Comment: It would help if you could create a workable example that mimics the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: I created the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/jLeyc6aw/2/
You can see that the dot is not animating. When you comment out the rAF in line 30 and 36 and comment in line 33, the dot is animating.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `requestAnimationFrame` but the way you are adding the `marker` to the map. In the `animateMarker` function you keep adding the marker every time it is called. This "resets" the marker and thus the animation. Check out your modified fiddle for example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmLag7s5/)

Comment: @EmielZuurbier you might want to post this as an answer, both the question and answers might help future readers. However Denis, that would be great if you could [edit] your question and at least include the problematic part, e.g your `animateMarker` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the problem in your code is not related to `requestAnimationFrame` but is the function that is being called by `rAF`.

In `animateMarker` you add the same marker every time `requestAnimationFrame` is called. This should be possible. However, because you want to show a CSS Keyframes animation on the marker, it will not work as you'd expect. This is because every time `marker.addTo(map)` is called, the marker is quickly removed and re-added. This will *reset* your keyframes animation.

Add the marker to map **outside** of the `animateMarker` function and only change the position of the marker. This will prevent the marker from being reset and get the result you want.

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2
});

var el = document.createElement('div');
var dot = document.createElement('div');
dot.className = 'mapboxgl-user-location-dot';
el.appendChild(dot);

// Set radius globally.
var radius = 20;

// Add marker before animate loop.
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
  .setLngLat(      
    Math.cos(0 / 1000) * 20,
    Math.sin(0 / 1000) * 20
  ]);
  .addTo(map);

// Change only the position in the animation loop without re-adding the marker.
function animateMarker(timestamp) {

  // Update the data to a new position based on the animation timestamp. The
  // divisor in the expression `timestamp / 1000` controls the animation speed.
  marker.setLngLat([
    Math.cos(timestamp / 1000) * radius,
    Math.sin(timestamp / 1000) * radius
  ]);  

  // Request the next frame of the animation.
  requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);
}

// Start the animation.
requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);
```